# return int if bool is true

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, boolean

I need an int bloodtype to equal to a particular value depending on which radio button is checked. If any bool is true it will make bloodtype equal to a particular value. I just dont know how to make the bool assign a value to int bloodtype. Any pointers?

```
private void btnAddPatient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)////Adds Patients using buttone etc to set properties
    {
        string name = txtPatientName.Text;
        int bloodType,x=1;           
         DateTime dob;
        bool bloodA = rbA.IsChecked.Equals(true);
        bool bloodB = rbB.IsChecked.Equals(true);
        bool bloodAB = rbAB.IsChecked.Equals(true);
        bool blood0 = rb0.IsChecked.Equals(true);



        if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null || txtPatientName.Text == "" || !bloodA || !bloodAB || !bloodB || !blood0)
        {

            if (txtPatientName.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Patient's Name");
            }

            else if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a date");
            }


            else if(!bloodA || !bloodAB || !bloodB || !blood0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter patient's blood type");
            }

        }

        else
        {
            //bloodType  How to make this equal to a value depending on what radio button is checked?
            dob = dpDOB.SelectedDate.Value;

            Patient patient = new Patient(name, bloodType, x, dob);

            MainWindow mainWindow = Owner as MainWindow;

            patients.Add(patient);
            lstPatients.ItemsSource = null;
            lstPatients.ItemsSource = patients;
            // this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just check with `if else if` , which radio button is true and assign the proper value ?

Comment: Where are the `int` values of bloodType defined?

Comment: Yes, I can. God I'm stupid at time.

Comment: I think a clever way to do it would be with an enum, since I don't know the integer values you're mapping each bloodtype to.

Comment: Care to share your enum method?  I want blood types to equal  0,1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `if else if`, for each radio button if it is true and assign the proper value.
Something like this:

```
            else
            {
                //bloodType  How to make this equal to a value depending on what radio button is checked?
                if(bloodA)
                {
                    bloodType = 0;
                }
                else if(bloodB)
                {
                    bloodType = 1;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

First, I suggest *extracting type*, `enum` to be exact:

```
  // [Flags] // you may want declare enum as Flags
  public enum BloodType {
     O = 0,
     A = 1,
     B = 2,
    AB = 3
  }
```

Then you can assign `BloodType` value with a help of ternary operator:

```
  BloodType bloodType = 
      rb0.IsChecked ? BloodType.O 
    : rbA.IsChecked ? BloodType.A
    : rbB.IsChecked ? BloodType.B
    : BloodType.AB;
```

if you want to get `int` value, just cast:

```
 int v = (int) bloodType;

 BloodType t = (BloodType) v;
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Definitely the most concise way to do it... you can define both `public enum BloodType { O, A, B, AB }` and your `BloodType bloodType = rb0.checked ? ... ` on single lines even. And a third line to cast the bloodType to an int.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not a friend of nested ifs, then another solution is to assign the int value to the Tag property of each radio button. Then, group all buttons within a group box, find out which one is checked, and finally cast the Tag content to your int.

```
int i;
var checkedButton = groupBox1.Controls
                .OfType<RadioButton>()
                .FirstOrDefault(rb => rb.Checked);            
if (int.TryParse(checkedButton.Tag.ToString(), out i))
{
    // here's your value 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one more:

**Prefer Strong Data Types. Use Enum over int.**

```
public enum BloodTypeEnum
{
    TypeO = 0,
    TypeA = 1,
    TypeB = 2
}
```

**Add an instance to your ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private BloodTypeEnum _bloodType;

    public BloodTypeEnum BloodType
    {
        get { return _bloodType; }
        set
        {
            _bloodType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Write your XAML using Strong Data Types and a ValueConverter**

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:EnumToBoolConverter x:Key="EnumToBoolConverter"></local:EnumToBoolConverter>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding BloodType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:BloodTypeEnum.TypeO}, Mode=TwoWay}">Type O</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding BloodType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:BloodTypeEnum.TypeA}, Mode=TwoWay}">Type A</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding BloodType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:BloodTypeEnum.TypeB}, Mode=TwoWay}">Type B</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**Implement the ValueConverter**

```
public class EnumToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return object.Equals(value, parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) ? parameter : DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```